# How to attach a button to a JSON object field and send the field to another webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I loop over a JSON object to populate dynamically a `<ul>` list.
Each `<li>` item has an `<input>` element with a click event attached to it.

Here follows my code

`index.html`

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col s12 l6">
      <ul id ="moduleList" class> </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

`js`

```
 var data = {
    "modules": [
        {
            "name": "mod1",
            "description": "mod1 description",
        },
        {
            "name": "mod2",
            "description": "mod2 description",
        },
        {
            "name": "mod3",
            "description": "mod3 description",
        }
    ]
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   
   $.each(data.modules, function(i, field){
           
           let module_name = field.name;
           let module_description = field.description;
           
           //build the html <li> element
           // add name and description info
           let li_html = "<div> Name: " + module_name + "</div>";
           li_html += "<div> Description: " + module_description + "</div>";
           
           //build the <input type="button"> element and add it to the li_html string               
           let select_button = "<div> <input class= \"set_inputs\" type=\"button\" value = \"select\"/> </div>";
           li_html +=select_button;

           // append the <li> item code to the <ul> element 
           $("<li />").html(li_html).appendTo("#moduleList");
           
           //attach the click event to current field        
           $(".set_inputs").click(function(){
              // save field info in the web browser
              localStorage.setItem('moduleObj', JSON.stringify(field));
              
              console.log("module id= " + i + " module_name= " + module_name );
              
              window.location.href = 'select_inputs.html';
           });
        });
     });
```

`select_inputs.html`

```
  [..]
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col s12 l6">
      <ul id ="moduleList" class> </ul>
   </div>
</div>
 [..]
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // get the active field 
    var retrivedModuleObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('moduleObj') || '{}');
    console.log("MODULE " + retrivedModuleObj.name);
    // remove the field from the web browser
    localStorage.removeItem("moduleObj");
  });
</script>
```

When I load index.html, I get the expected `name` + `description` text and a select button for each JSON field.

But when I click any button, in the console I get:

```
// index.html
module id= 1 module_name= mod2
module id= 2 module_name= mod3
//select_inputs.html
MODULE undefined
```

I have two issues:

1. in `index.html`, why clicking on one mod1 button, mod2 and mod3 fire the click event?
2. in `select_inputs.html`, the active field element is not received

I'm pretty new to js and can't understand what is going on.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT 1: as suggested, I change the code that retrieves the object field in `select_inputs.html`. This solves issue number 2, but something is still wrong in `index.html` since I always get

```
MODULE mod3
```

despite the button I click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You serialised the value you put in to localStorage to JSON. Therefore you need to deserialise it again when you try and read the value:

```
var retrivedModuleObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('moduleObj') || '{}');
console.log("MODULE " + retrivedModuleObj.name);
```

In addition, due to the loop completing before the `click` handler can be executed the `field` variable will only ever hold the value of the final iteration. A better approach would be to use a `data` attribute to hold the `field` related to each `button` element, and a delegated event handler to manage the click event on them. Try this:

```js
var data = {
  "modules": [{
    "name": "mod1",
    "description": "mod1 description",
  }, {
    "name": "mod2",
    "description": "mod2 description",
  }, {
    "name": "mod3",
    "description": "mod3 description",
  }]
}

jQuery($ => {
  $.each(data.modules, function(i, field) {
    let $li = $(`<li><div>Name: ${field.name}</div><div>Description: ${field.description}</div></li>`).appendTo('#moduleList');
    $('<input class="set_inputs" type="button" value="select" />').data('field', field).wrap('<div />').parent().appendTo($li);
  });


  $('#moduleList').on('click', '.set_inputs', e => {
    let $button = $(e.currentTarget);
    console.log($button.data('field'));
    
    // Uncomment these two lines in your production version. They are only commented 
    // here as they cause issues within SO snippets
    //localStorage.setItem('moduleObj', JSON.stringify($button.data('field')));
    //window.location.href = 'select_inputs.html';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 l6">
    <ul id="moduleList"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I made an edit to the question. Your suggestion solves issue number 2, but number 1 is still unsolved..

Comment: I edited the answer to provide a solution for that as well